# Getting IllegalFormatName exception in messageQueue.BeginReceive

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, msmq, .net-4.5.2

I am trying to create a eventhandler for a msmq message router and I almost just copied a online example from [msdn library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/43h44x53.aspx)
example 2.

But when I invoke messageQueue.BeginReceive() I get a IllegalFormatName exception.

- I am using a private queue
- Using VS 2015 on windows 10
- Solution is using .Net 4.5.2
- I got no problems sending messages to any of my private queues or reading from them if I use messageQueue.Receive()

Exception details below:

> System.Messaging.MessageQueueException was unhandled
>   ErrorCode=-2147467259   HResult=-2147467259   Message=Formatnavnet er
>   ugyldigt.   Source=System.Messaging   StackTrace:
>          ved System.Messaging.MessageQueue.MQCacheableInfo.get_ReadHandle()
>          ved System.Messaging.MessageQueue.ReceiveAsync(TimeSpan timeout, CursorHandle cursorHandle, Int32 action, AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object stateObject)
>          ved System.Messaging.MessageQueue.BeginReceive()
>          ved MYFirstMSMQ.Program.Main(String[] args) in ......Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FirstQueue_bluff_city\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:linje
>   68
>          ved System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>          ved System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>          ved Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          ved System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>          ved System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          ved System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          ved System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          ved System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()   InnerException:

Sorry about the Message - windows returns ***some*** messages in my native language

Comment: Are you sure, the async call with messageQueue.BeginReceive() is not creating an issue.

Comment: Sounds like a deserialization issue more than an MSMQ issue. Are you sure that you're setting up your queue formatter correctly?

Comment: The method will open the message queue if that was not yet done.  And clearly is is unhappy about the MessageQueue.FormatName property value.  Hard to guess why it is bad from the question of course.

Comment: What is the queue address you are using?

Comment: Can you provide the path name that you are using? I was getting this error too and it was an "$" missplaced...